# Xamarin - How to throw an unhandled exception to test AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException method

Tags: xamarin, testing, exception, unhandled

Added the following to the AppDelegate FinishedLaunching but was wondering how to test? Trying to just throw an exception that either of this will catch

```
// Catch exceptions from all threads in the AppDomain.
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += async (sender, args) => {
   await DialogService.ShowUnhandledExceptionMessage();
   HandleUnhandledException(args.ExceptionObject as Exception);
};

// Catch exceptions from each AppDomain that uses a task scheduler for async operations.
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += async (sender, args) => {
   await DialogService.ShowUnhandledExceptionMessage();
   HandleUnhandledException(args.Exception);
};
```

Comment: Just throw any exception without handling it in a try/catch? The biggest issue is that this will most certainly tear down your App. So showing any UI from here probably is too late.

Comment: So I have tried something such as that; throw new CannotUnloadAppDomainException(); App just closes and does not get to the HandleUnhandledException method. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: What are you expecting to do in the handler?  Usually this is a chance to do some logging and not much else

Comment: I figured out what was going on. The handler was failing due the type of exception I was throwing; there was no InnerException and I did not have a null check setup properly. App just crashed and debugger was not catching anything.